# Android: Limit the number of EditText fields editable at any one time to 2

Tags: android, android-edittext, limit

In my application I have five different EditText fields, all of which are numerical, but that is not important.

What is important is that I want only two of these to be editable in one go. For example, if I type in the first field, and the then the second, all the other fields become disabled. If I were then to remove the value from the first or second field, all the other fields would become editable once again, and if I added a second value elsewhere, the cycle would repeat.

In this way, I would be able to limit the number of fields "submitted" through the code to 2.

Is there a way I could achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes anything can be done. You probably need to make an object that holds the 5 EditTexts. Then there are probably a number of ways to do this, but I would use a TextWatcher set on each of the 5 EditTexts. Then when one of them is focused, get the text from all 5, see if the length of text is 0, and then do logic from there to disable or enable them appropriately.

See addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher watcher) in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher